# Engine Yard deploy failed while executing migration script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, engineyard

I am trying to deploy ruby on rails 2 based application using engine yard gem and get following error:

```
ey deploy --migrate=rake db:migrate
Beginning deploy for 'test' in 'test' on server...
~> Deploying revision 11111 Test commit.
~> Pushing code to all servers
~> Starting full deploy
~> Copying to /data/test/releases/20110928152454
~> Ensuring proper ownership
~> Preparing shared resources for release
~> Set group write permissions
~> Remove revision-tracked shared directories from deployment
~> Create tmp directory
~> Symlink shared log directory
~> Create public directory if needed
~> Create config directory if needed
~> Create system directory if needed
~> Symlink shared pids directory
~> Symlink other shared config files
~> Symlink mongrel_cluster.yml
~> Symlink database.yml
~> Symlink newrelic.yml if needed
~> Setting ownership to deploy:deploy
~> Migrating: cd /data/test/releases/20110928152454 && PATH=/data/test/releases/20110928152454/ey_bundler_binstubs:$PATH RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production NODE_ENV=production MERB_ENV=production rake
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again.
~> [Attention] Maintenance page still up, consider the following before removing:
* any deploy hooks ran, be careful if they were destructive
* any migrations ran, be careful if they were destructive
* your old code is still symlinked as current
Failed deployment recorded in AppCloud
Deploy failed
```

Has anyone face the same problem before?

Comment: Yes I have. Have not found a solution.

Comment: Same here, did anyone find a solution?